# Using awk in a subprocess in an f string

Tags: python, bash, awk

Trying to run an awk in a subprocess but pass that awk some variable using f strings

```
with open(file, 'w') as file:
 for file in glob.glob('*-ec2-*_dailyusage.json.csv'):
     command = f'awk "{{print {date} \",\" $0}}" "{file}" >> "{new_file}"'
 subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

I was expecting to append each column from the {file} into {new_file}

Comment: What is `new_file`?  You've got two different things defined as `file`, and nothing defined as `new_file`.

Comment: Running Awk as a subprocess of Python is just silly unless it's a substantial and complex script which cannot be rewritten in Python. `with open(new_file, "a") as dest: for line in file: newfile.write(','.join(date, line))`

Comment: (I forgot one `open` and there's some room for optimization; but you could probably get a working solution even from ChatGPT.)

Comment: The immediate problem is that you are using `file` for two different purposes; so your `for` loop variable will shadow the `file` you used for the output file in your `open`. Did you mean for that to be `new_file`? But you don't need Python to open the file at all; the shell is opening it for Awk in the redirection `>>{new_file}` (which of course should be a file name, not a Python object).

Comment: Or, conversely, you don't need Python: `awk -v date="whatever" '{ print date "," $0 }' *-ec2-*_dailyusage.json.csv >new_file`

Comment: Using string substitution to generate code (which is exactly what you're doing here) is a source of serious security problems. Don't: Pass your data and your code out-of-band from each other.

Comment: BTW, you're giving `file` several different meanings in your code. First it's a string with a filename opened for write, then it's the name of the file that results from that open operation, then it's a glob. In general, avoid reusing names -- use one name for the output file's name, a second name for the output file's handle, a third name for each input file name, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Demonstrating how to do this still calling awk from Python, but without the security and correctness problems of the prior approach:

```py
# open output file only once, for write
with open(new_file, 'w') as outfile:
    # loop over possible input files
    for infile_name in glob.glob('*-ec2-*_dailyusage.json.csv'):
        # open an input file
        with open(infile_name, 'r') as infile:
            # run awk with input from infile, appending to outfile
            subprocess.run(['awk',
                            '-v', f'date={date}',
                            '{print date "," $0}'],
                           stdin=infile, stdout=outfile)
```

(I wouldn't use awk for this use case myself, but this answer may be useful if you have a real-world use case with a more complex awk script that's tested/vetted and might not be trivial to rewrite in pure Python).

Note the pertinent changes:

- We aren't using `shell=True`. When using `shell=True`, your command (or, when the command is a list, the first element of that list) is parsed *as code*, which would allow a date of `$(rm -rf ~)` to delete your home directory; it also generally creates a new set of things to go wrong that you don't have any need for.
- We're substituting values only into awk as variables specified with `-v var=value`, not by injecting those values into code. Just as avoiding `shell=True` prevents values from having unexpected meanings *to your shell*, avoiding substituting into awk code prevents values from having unexpected meaning *to awk itself*.
- We're opening stdin and stdout *from Python*. Because we aren't using `shell=True`, there's no shell to recognize `>>file` and treat it as a directive telling it to open `file` for append; but `stdout=open('file', 'a')` has the same effect. Similarly, using `stdin=open('file', 'r')` ensures that the filename is treated exactly *as a filename* and can't be unexpectedly something with a different meaning to awk -- preventing still more potentially surprising behaviors.
- Because we're opening the output file *only once*, instead of re-opening it per copy of awk, we can open it for write, rather than for append. (This has the happy side effect that when you run your script twice, you don't get two copies of the output in a single file).

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Save the code as a separate file, make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""
name: foobar.py
usage:
./foobar.py > output.csv
"""
import glob
import time

from datetime import date
today = date.today()


for input_csv_fn in glob.glob("*-ec2-*_dailyusage.json.csv"):
     with open(input_csv_fn) as fh:
         for line in fh:
             out_line = f"{today},{line.strip()}"
             print(out_line)
```

Comment: The `.strip()` might be stripping more than the OP wants. Probably prefer `.rstrip()`, or use `print(out_line, end="")`. This writes to standand output, not to a new file.

Comment: I have my doubts about what a `*.json.csv` may contain. Stripping just the newline char should do the job as you pointed out.  Although I have a probably too strong opinion about extra spaces/tabs in CSVs ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use external libraries you might exploit [`awkupy`](https://pypi.org/project/awkupy/), after you install it you might use it following way, let say `file.txt` content is

```
ABLE
BAKER
CHARLIE
```

and you want to append text stored in python variable `x` before each line then you might use following code

```
from awkupy import Awk
x = "WORD"
awk = Awk()
awk.ACTION = f'{{print "{x}",$0}}'
awk.INPUT = 'file.txt'
awk()
```

which gives output

```
WORD ABLE
WORD BAKER
WORD CHARLIE
```

*(tested in python 3.10.12 and awkupy 0.1.0b0 and GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Let's say `x='hi" + system("rm -rf ~") + "world` -- using `f'{x}'` in a string awk will later evaluate directly as awk code means you're running `rm -rf ~` as the current user.

Comment: And it's a _completely unnecessary_ vulnerability, since awkupy lets you set `awk.opts.v` as a way to pass variables safely.